# vue: Count and check checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, count, checked

What I want to do with vue:

- Count checked checkboxes
- Set all checkboxes to checked (or uncheck all)

This is a very simplified model. The real website contains the following contraints:

- The number of checkboxes changes.
- The values are always different.
- I do not want to put all the input-attribute into the data-section of
  Vue

The following code allows to count the number of checked checkboxes.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc" value=1 v-model="cch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc" value=2 v-model="cch">
      <br/>
      Count: {{cch.length}}
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            cch: [],
          },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following code checks all checkboxes (and, of course, unchecks the checkboxes if chk=false):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc" value=1 :checked="chk">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc" value=2 :checked="chk">
      <br/>
      Checked: {{chk}}
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            chk: true
          },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems that it is not possible to use :checked and v-model in the same input-tag.
What can I do?

---

I have added a button to make all checkboxed checked and I have changed the names. The problems remain: the count works well, but the "all" button does not have any effect.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc1" value=1 v-model="cch" :checked="chk">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abc2" value=2 v-model="cch" :checked="chk">
      <br/>
      Count: {{cch.length}}
      <br/>
      <input type="button" @click="chk=!chk" value="all">
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            cch: [],
            chk: true
          },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a unique name-attribute to each checkbox. That way they work correctly with v-model.